# Can we submit (an updated version) of a work previously submitted to arXiv to a conference?

Tags: paper-submission

Is this possible to submit a newer verion of a paper  submitted on arXiv (which was never submited to any conferences before), to a new conference and then update arXiv with the new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

*Assuming the conference doesn't forbid that (many don't). If it does, then just update the arXiv version before submitting to the conference (or before signing anything).*

Comment: Thank you very much :), by the way, do you mean, its is actually possible to submit the same article on arXiv to a confrence ?

Comment: arXiv is a technical report repository. Technical reports are not considered "published," hence, they can be submitted elsewhere.

Comment: thank you very much, even if they were submited like years ago? i mean can I submit them to a journal as well? is that even a thing?

Comment: _even if they were submited like years ago? _yes_ _can I submit them to a journal as well?_ You can submit to a conference or a journal, but not simultaneously. You can't submit a conference paper to a journal without extending the paper, because the work has already been published.

Comment: Given that there are still journals that forbid preprints, I would be very surprised if there are no conferences with similar policies (depending on your field).

Comment: @user53923 I've never heard of a conference nor journal that forbids preprints, but I did quantify my answer to account for that very issue

Comment: @user53923 Oh, perhaps you meant _there are journals that will not publish anything that has previously appeared as a preprint_? Those journals are probably out of scope for the OP, because they've already made their manuscript available in the unpublished workshop proceedings.

Comment: @user2768 Yes that is what I meant. Indeed, these are out of scope for the OP. Thus the OP should check with any conference/journal they want to submit to, whether it is ok if a preprint already appeared. (Luckily, in my field, most conferences are indeed fine with this and some even encourage submitting technical reports to arxiv, so in practice this may be a non-issue)